# Html Agility Pack DocumentNode.SelectNodes returns null

Tags: c#, html, winforms, visual-studio-2017, html-agility-pack

Im having some trouble trying to find the value in an element. I think the reason is because it's only in divs and not in a table or something like that. I'm not sure but that is what is different from others' examples. 
This is my code:

```
private async void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load("https://hsreplay.net/decks/aeVbjoWFmDWILMwbMi9RCh/"));
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"mulligan - guide\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]");
    }
```

The var node returns null.The value Im trying to get is here:

89.3%

It is the value 89.3% Im trying to get.

Any help would be grealy appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The content you're trying to get is loaded asynchron via javascript. Try disabling javascript in the browser of your choice. What you see with javascript disabled is what you have if you load a webpage like you do. As far as I know the HtmlAgilityPack is powerful HTML parser, but it does not rendering anything. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might get what you want with this. Create a `WebBrowser` instance, setup the `DocumentCompleted` event handler (hopefully that means that javascript and stuff like that is also done when the event is fired). Then, when the handler is called, get the sourcecode of the `WebBrowser` (which has been hopefully updated by the scripts), create an `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` and fire your query on that.

```
using(var ie = new WebBrowser())
{
    ie.DocumentCompleted += (s, args) => 
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(ie.DocumentText);
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"mulligan - guide\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]");
    };
    ie.Navigate("https://hsreplay.net/decks/aeVbjoWFmDWILMwbMi9RCh/");
}
```

**not tested**

Comment: I tried it and it complains about the "sender". Error: CS0163.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you're able to solve this error if you read the error description ;)